# How to retrieve IPV6 ip's from a mysql db if they are stored in INT(10) UNSIGNED

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mysql db with a table where ipv4 and ipv6 ip's are stored as `INT(10) UNSIGNED` .
To retrieve the ipv4 ip address I use function `INET_NTOA`:

`SELECT INET_NTOA( client_ip ) FROM mytable1;`

Works great for ipv4 ip's. BUT all ipv6 ip's do return as:

`6.0.0.0`

If I try to retrieve ipv4 and ipv6 ip's using function `INET6_NTOA ( client_ip )` or `INET6_NTOA(UNHEX( client_ip ))` it doesn't work, I just get output:

`NULL`

`INET6_NTOA ( client_ip )`

OR:

`NULL`

`INET6_NTOA(UNHEX( client_ip ))`

Is there any other way to retrieve the ipv6 ip's from my db? 
Need to do this in bash.

DB version: 10.2.12-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Comment: An `int` isn't large enough to store an IPV6 address. Reading the literature on this function, it seems that a VARBINARY(16) would be more appropriate for storing both IPV4 and IPV6 together. An ipv4 only needs 4 bytes, but the IPV6 needs another 96 bits to store the full length.

Answer (score 2):

An `INT(10) UNSIGNED` column is [4 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html), i.e., 32 bits.

An IPv6 address is [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Larger_address_space).

Any IPv6 addresses you have stored in that column will have been truncated and cannot be recovered.

To store IPv6 addresses in MySQL use `VARBINARY(16)` (which is returned by [`INET6_ATON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton)) or `BINARY(16)`.